# Android Studio 0.8 installer

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an app I wrote in ~July of 2014 with Android Studio 0.8, build AI-135.1245622

The system I wrote this on is long since dead and modern versions of Android Studio have left my app hopelessly uncompileable. I'm looking to install 0.8 then, I found it here: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/0-8-0

But apparently you have to have a prior version installed to be able to use it, it complains about missing DLLs on startup and advises to re-install but there's no installer.

Any idea how I can install it?

Comment: Fix your app instead of messing up your Android Studio install.

Comment: I wish to compile it with the old env so that I can side load it onto an old phone and also just for nostalgic purposes. I have no intention of porting it forward.

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's easier to port the app than to try to work out an old (beta) install of Android Studio.

Comment: Ok, I needed this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=26999